# Why can't I insert these values into the table I added to this database?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

I'm new to SQL and learning its basic functions, i've been instructed to create a table and add it to my database, whilst then adding the appropriate values to each field in the table. But I keep getting a syntax error in the line:

```
INSERT into Weather_db.client_data
```

Here is my code so far. Let me know what I should change:

Q1.) Using the CREATE TABLE statement, create a table called client_data with fields

```
CREATE TABLE Weather_db.client_data (
ID int PRIMARY KEY,
First_name varchar(40) NOT NULL, 
Last_name varchar(40),
Nationality varchar(40), 
Age Float Check (age>18))
```

Q2.) Insert the following records in the database using the INSERT statement

```
INSERT into Weather_db.client_data 
VALUES ('John', 'S',
'British', 'null'), 
('Peter', 'Jackson', 'null', '20'), 
('Tom', 'W', 'null', '20'), 
('Jack', 'Patrick', 'American', '30');
```

Comment: First you are declaring 5 columns and insert 4 values. If you want to use insert into values and do not want to iclude column you have to change to : `insert into Weather_db.client_data (First_name ,Last_name ,Nationality ,Age ) ....` Second `Age Float Check (age>18) ` will fail for `null` and `ID int PRIMARY KEY` does not have a default value

Comment: @ErgestBasha CHECK constraints are satisfied by a result of UNKNOWN, so they effectively ignore cases where the column is NULL.

Comment: @BillKarwin yeah you are right, it gave me error data truncated for row 1 , but I guess was because of `ID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement has a few syntax issues.

Firstly you are not providing values for all the defined columns.

It's also good practice to always specifically list the columns in the insert statement.

You should not be quoting numeric values, or null values.

You should probably define the ID as *auto_increment* which means the database will supply a default value.

See a [working example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6b42039cbe5c56e94b116ed46429a4f0)

```
CREATE TABLE client_data (
ID int PRIMARY key auto_increment,
First_name varchar(40) NOT NULL, 
Last_name varchar(40),
Nationality varchar(40), 
Age Float Check (age>18));

INSERT into client_data (first_name, last_name, Nationality, Age)
VALUES ('John', 'S','British', null), 
('Peter', 'Jackson', null, 20), 
('Tom', 'W', null, 20), 
('Jack', 'Patrick', 'American', 30);
```

Comment: Thanks, I've changed my code. But I still keep getting the error 1136 that 'column count doesn't match value count at row 1. How do I insure that the ID column gets filled? I thought instructing the PRIMARY key to auto_increment would work on its own?

Answer (score 1):

```
ID int PRIMARY KEY,
```

This column definition is legal, but it doesn't have any automatic behavior to generate unique values. So you must supply a value yourself in your INSERT statement, and it's up to you to make sure the value is unique, i.e. it is not already used on any existing row in this table.

MySQL provides an option for integer primary keys to generate new unique values automatically:

```
ID int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
```

By using this, you don't have to specify a value in your INSERT statement.

You may like to read this manual page for more information: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-auto-increment.html